# Proving that $\operatorname{Sp} (n)$ is a group

Tags: group-theory, symplectic-linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove that the [symplectic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group) is, indeed, a group. It was easy to show that the operation is closed and the neutral element is inside the group itself, but I'm stuck trying to show that the inverse belongs to $\operatorname{Sp} (n)$.

The group is defined as follows:

$$\text{Sp}(n,\mathbf{R})=\{M\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbf{R}) : M^T\Omega M=\Omega\},$$

where $\Omega$ is defined as an $n \times n$ matrix with $I_{\frac{n}{2}}$ and $-I_{\frac{n}{2}}$ in the non-diagonal inputs, and 0 elsewhere.

The inverse of any element in the group should be

$M^{-1} = \Omega^T M^T J$.

But when computing

$$(M^{-1})^T \Omega M^{-1} = \Omega$$

it follows that

$$(M^{-1})^T \Omega M^{-1} = \Omega^T M J M^T J,$$

and I don't know how to continue. Any hint?

Comment: You're making life too complicated for yourself. Just multiply the defining identity $M^T \Omega M = \Omega$ by $(M^T)^{-1}$ on the left and $M^{-1}$ on the right. What do you get?

Comment: Is $J$ supposed to be $Ω$?

Comment: I have the same confusion (see my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4703401/882595)). The suggestion by @QiaochuYuan is just my "Route 1" there. And "Route 2" is the concern by the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment by QiaochuYuan, note that:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&M^T\Omega M=\Omega \iff \\
&(M^T)^{-1}\Omega M^{-1}=\Omega \iff \\
&(M^{-1})^T\Omega M^{-1}=\Omega
\end{alignat}
and hence:
$$M\in\operatorname{Sp}(n,{\bf R})\iff M^{-1}\in\operatorname{Sp}(n,\bf R)$$