# Prove the inverse of a symplectic matrix is also symplectic

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A [symplectic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix) is a $2n \times 2n$ matrix $M$ satisfying the condition

$$
M^\mathsf{T} \Omega M = \Omega
\tag{1}
$$

where the matrix $\Omega$ is usually chosen as the block matrix

$$
\Omega = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & I_n \\ -I_n & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which satisfies $\Omega^{-1} = \Omega^\mathsf{T} = -\Omega$. The inverse of $M$ exists, and is found from Eq. (1) as

$$
M^{-1} = \Omega^{-1} M^\mathsf{T} \Omega
= -\Omega M^\mathsf{T} \Omega
\tag{2}
$$

However, I am having trouble in showing that $M^{-1}$ is also symplectic, i.e. also satisfy the defining property Eq. (1):

$$
(M^{-1})^\mathsf{T} \Omega M^{-1} = \Omega
\tag{3}
$$

- Route 1: Multiply Eq. (1) on the right by $M^{-1}$, and on the left by $(M^\mathsf{T})^{-1} = (M^{-1})^\mathsf{T}$, I can produce Eq. (3)

  $$
  \Omega = (M^{-1})^\mathsf{T} \Omega M^{-1}
  $$
- Route 2: Taking inverse of Eq. (1), I get

  $$
  \begin{align*}
      M^{-1} \Omega^{-1} (M^\mathsf{T})^{-1} &= \Omega^{-1}
      \\
      \Rightarrow \quad
      M^{-1} \Omega (M^{-1})^\mathsf{T} &= \Omega
  \end{align*}
  $$

  which does not seem to lead to Eq. (3).

*Question*: How can I arrive at Eq. (3) using Route 2? Alternatively, can symplectic matrices be *equivalently* defined using the following condition

$$
M \Omega M^\mathsf{T} = \Omega \quad ?
\tag{4}
$$

Comment: For Route 2, apply both inversion and transpose to get equ (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M$ is invertible because $\det(M^T)\det(\Omega)\det(M)=\det(\Omega)\implies\det(M^T)\det(M)=1$ since $\det(\Omega)=\pm 1$.

Now, $\Omega$ is also invertible. So, taking inverses of Eq. (1) you get,

$(M^T\Omega M)^{-1}=\Omega^{-1}$.

$M^{-1}\Omega^{-1}(M^T)^{-1}=\Omega^{-1}$.

Since $\Omega^{-1}=-\Omega$ and $(M^T)^{-1}=(M^{-1})^T$, we obtain

$(M^{-1})\Omega (M^{-1})^T=\Omega$.

Now premultiply by $M$ and postmultiply by $M^T$.

$\Omega=M\Omega M^T$.

So $M^T$ is symplectic. But $(M^{-1})\Omega (M^{-1})^T=\Omega$ shows that $(M^{-1})^T$ is symplectic. Thus, $M^{-1}$ is also symplectic as your matric is still symplectic after taking tranposes.

Comment: Lots of transposition in Route 2... Thank you!